# How can I find an element and remove all following elements?

Tags: arrays, perl

In other words, I would like to port this simple C++ program to Perl 5:

```cpp
vector<string> vec { "a", "bb", "ccc", "cd", "ee" };
// find first element starting with "cc"
auto found_it = find_if(begin(vec), end(vec), 
                        [](auto& elem) { return elem.starts_with("cc"); });
// if found, remove all following elements
if (found_it != end(vec)) { vec.erase(found_it + 1, end(vec)); }
```

The result should be `("a", "bb", "ccc")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One occassion when iterating by index may be useful

```
foreach my $i (0..$#ary) {
    if ($ary[$i] =~ /^cc/) {
        $#ary = $i;  # shortens the array: last index is now $i
        last;
    }
}
```

The syntax `$#arrayname` is for the index of the last element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

One way is using [`before_incl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#before_incl-BLOCK-LIST) from the [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use List::MoreUtils qw/before_incl/;

my @vec = ("a", "bb", "ccc", "cd", "ee");
@vec = before_incl { /^cc/ } @vec;
say "@vec"; # a bb ccc
```

---

Or a more imperative approach using a loop and `splice`:

```perl
my @vec = ("a", "bb", "ccc", "cd", "ee");
for (my $n = 0; $n < $#vec; $n += 1) {
    if ($vec[$n] =~ /^cc/) {
        splice @vec, $n + 1;
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also available in `List::AllUtils` and `List::SomeUtils`. There's a lot of list utility modules...

Answer (score 2):

Other variation of perl code to the problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @vec = ("a", "bb", "ccc", "cd", "ee");
my $regex = qr/^cc/;
my $index = 0;

for( @vec ) {
    last if /$regex/;
    $index++;
}

@vec = @vec[0..$index];

say Dumper(\@vec);
```